# Xamarin.Forms Dependency Service non-static fields/properties

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I'm using Dependency Service to get the platform specific implementation of an interface.
Let's say I have the following interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

And the implementing class in my Android project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyClass))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    class MyClass : IMyInterface
    {
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

At some point in the code, I set `IsEnabled` to `true`.

After that, I start a new activity that makes my app go to background:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetAction(action);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(intent);
```

When my app returns to foreground, I access the property `IsEnabled` and I get `false` instead of `true`. This actually happens with every single property and private field of the impementing class. Are those properties garbage collected when I leave the app for a new activity?

The only way I found to solve this issue is to make all backing fields `static`, but this makes a lot of overhead in the code, which might be unnecessary if I knew the reasons under this behavoiur.

Comment: Are you sure that in your Android project you access exactly the same instance as  in Xamarin.Forms project? E.g. if you use DependencyService.Get<MyClass >() in Xamarin.Forms and new MyClass, for sure the instances will be different... I'd expect that in MyClass there should be to a reference to another class instance, e.g. singleton, which stores some state and which one's lifetime is separated from the MyClass instance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well, in my Android Project I never instanciate the class. I only instanciate it in the portable project. In Xamarin.Forms I have an instance and before starting the activity my instance properties are set with some values/references, but after the new activity, still in Xamarin.Forms, all those instance properties now are with default values or null. But the class in the android project still "works" with its methods, so I think I'm gonna use the singleton pattern as you suggested and I'll let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Check comments on the answer for last updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too understanding the title of your question.

**If** you use the singleton pattern, you can extract the properties based on the unique instantiation object when needed.Like this:

```
public class Singleton
    {
        // Define a static variable to hold an instance of the class
        private static Singleton uniqueInstance;

        // Define a private constructor so that the outside world cannot create instances of the class
        private Singleton()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Define public methods to provide a global access point, and you can also define public properties to provide global access points
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Singleton GetInstance()
        {
            // Create if the instance of the class does not exist, otherwise return directly
            if (uniqueInstance == null)
            {
                uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
            }
            return uniqueInstance;
        }
    }
```

**If not**, you can use `Properties` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.properties?view=xamarin-forms)to access the data .Like this:

```
private void SaveConnectionData(JSON.Connection C)
                    {
                        App.Current.Properties[Cryptography.Encryption("AccessToken")] = Cryptography.Encryption(C.Access_token);
                        App.Current.Properties[Cryptography.Encryption("ExpiresIn")] = Cryptography.Encryption(C.Expires_in.ToString());
                        App.Current.Properties[Cryptography.Encryption("TokenType")] = Cryptography.Encryption(C.Token_type);
                        App.Current.Properties[Cryptography.Encryption("Scope")] = Cryptography.Encryption(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(C.Scope));
                        App.Current.Properties[Cryptography.Encryption("RefreshToken")] = Cryptography.Encryption(C.Refresh_token);
                        App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                    }
```

You may be involved in the use of `lifecycles` and `notifications`.Also if there is a lot of data, consider using  the `SQLite` database to save this data .Can refer to this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases)

*More*:In Xamarin.Android, you also can try `lifecycles` to show saved data.Like `OnResume` method to show data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your accurate answer. I'll try this soon and I will let you know. Also in the comments to the quesiton, another user suggested me to use the singleton pattern and that is what I'm going to do next.

Comment: Ok, if be helpful please tell me,then you can vote it.

Comment: Well, I tried to implement it, but there is something to say here. First, the class (`MyClass` in the example) I want to make singleton derives from another class that has a public constructor. This prevents me from having a singleton. Second, I retrieve the implementing class with `var service = DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface>();` which returns by default a global instance, so it is already kind of `singleton`. I'll find a way to do what I say in the question, maybe considering the other parts in your answer about database, etc. If so, I'll mark your anwer as correct.

Comment: @Maxim Saplin @Junior Jiang - MSFT, I just discovered that two instances of `MyClass` were created. This should be the reason of my issue. I just discovered that this occurs since `MyClass` implements another class that is automatically instanciated whenever something specific occurs (the code in my question is just an example and is not complete). Knowing this, I can handle everything properly. Thank you both, you helped me find this. I will accept the answer since would be correct in a normal case, but in my case there was something more I didn't post in my question that made the difference.

Comment: Great,glad that you found the reason and solved the problem!